# How to submit and embed video from other sites on Reddit?

Tags: html, video, embed, meta, reddit

I'm trying to embed video from [Rumble](http://rumble.com) but for some reason it fails. I've added the correct og meta tags and tested it out with the Facebook Link Debugger which works properly and displays the video. I want to display the video as shown in the [/r/Videos subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/videos/).

Here is an example of what i have on my page:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="video">
<meta property="og:video" content="LINK_TO_VIDEO">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="text/html">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="480">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="360">
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include both the og:video and og:video:secure_url tags. Use the HTTPS link to the video for both.

```
<meta property="og:video" content="LINK_TO_VIDEO">
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="LINK_TO_VIDEO">
```